# How to correct Fortran runtime error: End of file

Tags: file, fortran

I have a code `uno.f90` that saves the numbers from `1` to `100` in `out_1.txt`, and I have a second code `dos.f90` which saves the square of each number in `out_2.txt`. It fulfills its objective, but when running the file I get the following message in the terminal:

```
At line 13 of file dos.f90 (unit = 33, file = 'out_1.txt')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

*Termination error. back trace:*
#0 0x7fdbe6dab32a
#1 0x7fdbe6dabed5
#2 0x7fdbe6dac69d
#3 0x7fdbe6f22ca3
#4 0x7fdbe6f1bc44
#5 0x7fdbe6f1d379
#6 0x555ca8109ad4
#7 0x555ca8109b9e
#8 0x7fdbe69c0bf6
#9 0x555ca8109879
#10 0xffffffffffffffff
```

this happens when I run `dos.f90` using the following sequence:

```
gfortran -o dos dos.f90
./dos
```

The Fortran code is

```
program two
!integer,dimension(100) :: i(1)
integer::i
open(unit=33,file='out_1.txt',status='unknown',action='read')
open(unit=35,file='out_2.txt',status='new',action='write')

do
read(33,*)i
write(35,*,IOSTAT=ios)i**2
enddo

 close(33)
 close(35)

end program two
```

and `uno.f90` is

```
program one

open(unit=33, file='out_1.txt', status='new')
do i=1,100
    write(33,*,iostat=ios) i
enddo
 close(33)
end program one
```

I would like to be able to correct the error indicated in the terminal because, although the objective comes out, the terminal exits with said error warning.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Please note that Fortran 90 is just one very old revision of the standard. The suffix .f90 is used for all free-form Fortran source files, not just the old Fortran 90.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop

```
do
read(33,*)i
write(35,*,IOSTAT=ios)i**2
enddo
```

you have no loop termination condition, so the loop will keep going forever, or until it is stopped unexpectedly. In this case, it stops unexpectedly when the program gets to the end of the file.

The best way of terminating the loop is to check when you are at the end of the file, using the `iostat` flag in the `read` statement just like you've used it in the `write` statement, e.g.

```
integer :: ios

do
  read(33,*,iostat=ios)i
  if (ios<0) then
    exit
  endif
  write(35,*,iostat=ios)i**2
enddo
```

Note also that in your code the variable `ios` is not explicitly declared, but gets implicitly declared because you are not using `implicit none`. You should really use `implicit none` and declare `ios` explicitly, otherwise you are going to miss a lot of bugs in the future.

Comment: Shouldn't `if (iostat<0) then` ve `if (ios<0) then`?